# ARM Template for QnAmaker to output subscription key

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-qna-maker

I'm working on creating an ARM template for a QnAMaker resource type in Azure. After creating a QnAMaker resource and exporting the template it creates a number of resources:

1. "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts" of kind "QnAMaker"
2. "Microsoft.Search/searchServices"
3. "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
4. "Microsoft.Web/sites" including appsettings including `"PrimaryEndpointKey": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '-PrimaryEndpointKey')]"`

The ARM template has a hardcoded value in the "/sites" resource rather than picking it up from another resource.

In the outputs, there is a link to qna runtime:

```
"qnaRuntimeEndpoint": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[concat('https://',reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName'))).hostNames[0])]"
        }
```

**What should the output value be for retrieving a subscription key for the QnAMaker resource?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses cognitive services related functions. Looking at some other examples I arrived at...

```
"outputs": {
  "qnaKey":{
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[listKeys(concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/','Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/', parameters('name')),'2016-02-01-preview').key1]"
  }
}
```

[Cognitive Services API docs for listKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/accountmanagement/accounts/listkeys)